# Amazon EC2 SSH: Permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, permissions

I just created a new instance with Ubuntu (natty) AMI. After logging in with `ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@ip` user, I did `sudo adduser timmy` and added timmy to admin, `sudo adduser timmy admin`. But when I try to login with username `ssh -i key.pem timmy@ip` it reutrns: `Permission denied (publickey).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add timmy to the admin group:

```
usermod -a -G admin timmy
```

(The -a flag will keep timmy in any secondary groups that he's already in.)

You should set a password for timmy:

```
passwd timmy
```

Make sure you can log in with passwords. Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and check that the following line is present:
    PasswordAuthentication yes

(If not change it and run `/etc/init.d/ssh reload` You can change it [back] to `PasswordAuthentication no` once you get this working.)

And if you want to use that key to log in as timmy (in addition to logging in as ubuntu), you need to copy the public key to timmy's account your local machine (assuming you are on a linux machine):

```
ssh-copy-id -i key.pem timmy@ip
```

The fist time, you'll have to enter timmy's password.

EDIT:

"I did cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/timmy/.ssh/authorized_keys"

Make sure permissions are correct on /home/timmy/.ssh

```
chmod -R 600 /home/timmy/.ssh
chown -R timmy /home/timmy/.ssh
```

Comment: When I do `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh reload` I get 
`Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service ssh reload

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the reload(8) utility, e.g. reload ssh
`

Comment: Ok, use `service ssh reload` or `reload ssh`

Comment: Thanks, `PasswordAuthentication yes` helped. But, if I change it to `no`, the problem exists. Is it okay to keep it on?

Comment: Yes, however if you do, you should use something like [denyhosts](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/securing-ssh.html) because your sever will be probed by bots. **But** if you cannot log in with `PasswordAuthentication no`, then you didn't get the keys working right. Are you prompted for a password if you do `ssh -i key.pem timmy@ip`?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for the user ubuntu over to timmy. Either that or a safer option would be to create a new [ssh key pair](http://w3.pppl.gov/cppg/seminars/papers/linux_talk/node11.html) for timmy.

Comment: I did `cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/timmy/.ssh/authorized_keys` but it still returns that error

Comment: Check the permission on `timmy/.ssh/authorized_keys`. It should be 600. If you want to generate a new key just follow the link above.

Comment: Thank you! It works. I had to `chmod 600 `

Answer (score 0):

You must place the public portion of the key in `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Also, you may want to create a new key set for this user (with `ssh-keygen`)

Comment: `/home/.ssh: No such file or directory`